# iPhone with USB does not allow internet on Rp

Tags: usb, hotspot

I have a iPhone that I share internet with on my MacBook pro, and windows pc fine with. I am familiar with the set up. I have used it correctly. I have just bought a Raspberry Pi 4 today and I am very familiar with debian but I cannot for the life of me get the iPhone to connect it's usb tethered hotspot. I do have (however) access to "digital photos" but not the hotspot.

- I have added `raspi-config` -> `Advanced Options` -> `A4 Network Interface Names` `Enable Predicatble names` - `YES`
- i have `sudo apt full-upgrade`
- in "wireless and wired network settings" I can see [interface] -> enp1s0u..... eth0 and wlan0
- if I plug  in my android usb to tether it works fine
- if I plug my iPhone into mac or pc it works fine
- I have installed `sud apt install usbmuxd`

any ideas? as I say this is a brand new raspberry pi 4